# Using where in sas macro when subsetting dataset

Tags: macros, subset, where-clause

I'm trying to use where in a macro when subsetting a dataset

```
     option mprint mlogic;

     %macro subset_by_make (dsn, make);
        data temp;
            set &dsn(where = (make = &make));
    run;
    %mend subset_by_make;
    %subset_by_make(sashelp.cars, Acura);
```

but I'm getting an error that Variable `Acura` is not on file `SASHELP.CARS`

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your macro generates valid SAS syntax. In this case you did not include quotes around the string literal, so SAS interpreted the string `Acura` generated by the macro as a variable name.

```
%macro subset_by_make (dsn, make);
  data temp;
    set &dsn(where = (make = "&make"));
  run;
%mend subset_by_make;
```